# How to add cutting marks aligned with elements on the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, cropmarks

I am working on a memory card game for my pupils and have set up a grid of 6cm x 6cm cards which looks like this:

[image]

Problem is that I am very bad at using this cutting machine and always miss the lines. So I would like to add cutting marks on all borders which are aligned with the grid lines. This way I could do a little cut and see if it is on spot or not.

The grid is being generated as described here: https://newbedev.com/foreach-loop-inside-the-tikz-picture-creation-of-memory-cards-using-tikz I adapted it only a bit so in my case it looks this way:

```
%%% Global Setup
\newcommand\xspacing{86pt}%<== space between the images
\newcommand\yspacing{86pt}%<== vertical space between rows
\newcommand\imgperrow{4}%<== number of images per row

%%% Define primary for loop
\newcommand{\forloop}[2]{%
    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {#1,...,#2}%<==loop for each image in the array
    {
        \edef\gonode{\noexpand\node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\noexpand\includegraphics[width=6cm]{\getimage{\x}}};}%<==Edit to expand the file name
        \gonode%
        \draw [black, ultra thick] ($(B.north west)$) rectangle ($(B.south east)$);%
        \pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,\imgperrow)==0?1:0};%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
        \coordinate (left) at ([yshift=-\yspacing]left);
        \path let \p1=(left),\p2=(B.south) in coordinate (A) at (\x1,\y2-\yspacing);
        \else   
        \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=\xspacing]B.east);%
        \fi
}}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %first page
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{1}{24}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now I am a bit lost and don't know whether it is possible to access the coordinates of the grid lines (actually rectangles, as you see from the code) and put cut marks on the borders at those positions.

Addendum: Here's the complete code. I tried to strip off what is unnecessary.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% ############################## geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headsep = 0pt,
    headheight= 0pt, 
    hmarginratio =  1:1,
    vmarginratio = 1:1,
    bindingoffset = 0cm,
    onecolumn,
    a3paper,
    layoutwidth = 240 mm,
    layoutheight = 360 mm,
    layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax,
    layoutvoffset=\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2\relax,
    showcrop
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}


% ############################### Document

\newcommand{\czHyphen}{\rule[.45ex]{.2em}{.11ex}}
\newcommand*{\addthinS}{\hskip0.06667em\relax}
\newcommand*{\addthinSS}{\hskip0.00007em\relax}
\def\cropmarkgap{1}% mm

\makeatletter
\def\Gm@cropmark(#1,#2,#3,#4){% #1 = x direction, #2 = y direction, #3 & #4 no longet used
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \setlength\unitlength{1truemm}%
        \linethickness{0.25pt}%
        \put(\the\numexpr #1*\cropmarkgap\relax,0){\line(#1,0){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
        \put(0,\the\numexpr #2*\cropmarkgap\relax){\line(0,#2){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
\end{picture}}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\AddToShipoutPicture{\drawbackground}
\newcommand{\shiftleft}{\hspace*{-0.55\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}
\newcommand{\shiftup}{\vspace*{-0.13\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}


%%% Define "Array" interface
\makeatletter
\newcounter{imgs}
\setcounter{imgs}{0}
%#1 is the image
\newcommand{\addimg}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{imgs}%
    \@namedef{imgimage\theimgs}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\getimage}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgimage#1}}%
\newcommand{\gettitle}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgtitle#1}}%
\newcommand{\getcolor}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgcolor#1}}%
\makeatother

%%% Define Cards
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-equation}

%%% Global Setup
\newcommand\xspacing{86pt}%<== space between the images
\newcommand\yspacing{86pt}%<== vertical space between rows
\newcommand\imgperrow{4}%<== number of images per row}

%%% Define primary for loop
\newcommand{\forloop}[2]{%
    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {#1,...,#2}%<==loop for each image in the array
    {
        \edef\gonode{\noexpand\node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\noexpand\includegraphics[width=6cm]{\getimage{\x}}};}%<==Edit to expand the file name
        \gonode%
        \draw [black, ultra thick] ($(B.north west)$) rectangle ($(B.south east)$);%
        \pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,\imgperrow)==0?1:0};%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
        \coordinate (left) at ([yshift=-\yspacing]left);
        \path let \p1=(left),\p2=(B.south) in coordinate (A) at (\x1,\y2-\yspacing);
        \else   
        \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=\xspacing]B.east);%
        \fi
}}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %page1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.61,0.715);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{1}{24}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add your preamble? Although you posted the link to the code that serves as the basis for yours, I am not fully sure how you ended adapting it.

Comment: Sure, I added the complete code in another code block!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the feeling that your code is a bit more complicated than necessary. Anyways, I would not use the crop marks provided by `geometry` but just draw custom ones using Ti*k*Z. The following code hopefully can help you.

I deleted large parts of the original code, since I thought them to be unnecessary for your concrete example. I defined four new macros that contain different dimensions, namely `\shiftright`, `\shiftdown`, `\imgwidth` and `\imgheight`.

I finally defined a new macro `\cropmarks` that takes two arguments, namely the number of columns and the number of rows, and that prints out cropmarks between ech row and column. I hope this is what you wanted.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% ############################## geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headsep = 0pt,
    headheight= 0pt, 
    hmarginratio =  1:1,
    vmarginratio = 1:1,
    bindingoffset = 0cm,
    onecolumn,
    a3paper,
    layoutwidth = 240mm,
    layoutheight = 360mm,
    layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax,
    layoutvoffset=\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2\relax,
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% ############################### Document

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shiftright}{\dimexpr\Gm@layouthoffset\relax}
\newcommand{\shiftdown}{\dimexpr\Gm@layoutvoffset\relax}
\makeatother

%%% Define "Array" interface
\makeatletter
\newcounter{imgs}
\setcounter{imgs}{0}
%#1 is the image
\newcommand{\addimg}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{imgs}%
    \@namedef{imgimage\theimgs}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\getimage}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgimage#1}}%
\makeatother

%%% Define Cards
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-1-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-2-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-3-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-4-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-two-points}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-5-equation}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-graph}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-point-and-slope}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-point-and-shift}
\addimg{tex-s2JJAi-6-equation}

%%% Global Setup
\newcommand\imgwidth{6cm}   %<== width of images
\newcommand\imgheight{6cm}  %<== height of images
\newcommand\xspacing{0pt}   %<== space between the images
\newcommand\yspacing{0pt}   %<== vertical space between rows
\newcommand\imgperrow{4}    %<== number of images per row

%%% Define primary for loop
\newcommand{\forloop}[2]{%
    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {#1,...,#2}%<==loop for each image in the array
    {
        \edef\gonode{\noexpand\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west] (B) at (A) 
            %{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=\imgheight]{example-image-a}};}  % just for testing purposes
            {\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=\imgheight]{\getimage{\x}}};} 
        \gonode%
        \draw [black, ultra thick] ($(B.north west)$) rectangle ($(B.south east)$);%
        
        \pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,\imgperrow)==0?1:0};%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
        
            \coordinate (left) at ([yshift=-\yspacing]left);
            \path let \p1=(left),\p2=(B.south) in coordinate (A) at (\x1,\y2-\yspacing);
            
        \else   
        
            \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=\xspacing]B.north east);%

        \fi
}}

\newcommand{\cropmarks}[2]{ % #1 = number of columns, #2 = number of rows
    \draw[thin] ([yshift={10pt}]A) -- ++(0,2);%

    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {0,...,#1} {
        \draw[thin] ([yshift={-\shiftdown+10pt}, xshift={\shiftright+(\i-1)*\imgwidth}]current page.north west) -- ++(0,2);
        \draw[thin] ([yshift={\shiftdown-10pt}, xshift={\shiftright+(\i-1)*\imgwidth}]current page.south west) -- ++(0,-2);
    }
    
    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {0,...,#2} {
        \draw[thin] ([xshift={\shiftright-10pt}, yshift={-\shiftdown-(\i-1)*\imgheight}]current page.north west) -- ++(-2,0);
        \draw[thin] ([xshift={-\shiftright+10pt}, yshift={-\shiftdown-(\i-1)*\imgheight}]current page.north east) -- ++(2,0);
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %page1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=\shiftright, yshift=-\shiftdown]current page.north west);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{1}{24}
        
        \cropmarks{4}{6}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great, thanks a lot! I will try to use it and report back asap. You are absolutely right that the code is most probably not very elegant, the reason for it being that I am not very proficient with TeX and thus copied the code from the blog entry which I referred to without actually fully understanding it. Just made some changes such that it works for my use case and that's it...

Comment: Me again, works like a charm, thanks again! I'm actually generating the file using PHP and needed to combine the improved template with the PHP code but it worked out just fine!